# How to build project with msbuild with different configuration, but build dependencies in Debug/Release?

Tags: c#, docker, msbuild

I have a `main_project` project with "new" configuration (`Dev` -> `<Configurations>Debug;Release;Dev</Configurations>` in `csproj` file) to copy correct file name during build. This project has other projects as dependencies, but with standard configurations (`Debug` and `Release`).

In **Visual Studio** I can rebuild this project without any problems - my `main_project` is builded with `Dev` configuration and dependencies projects are builds with `Debug` configuration:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: x.BusinessLogic, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  x.BusinessLogic -> C:\xxx\Libs\x.BusinessLogic\bin\Debug\x.x.BusinessLogic.dll
------ Rebuild All started: Project: main_project, Configuration: Dev Any CPU ------
C:\xxx\Server\CloudService\WebJobs\main_project\\config\App.dev.config
1 File(s) copied
main_project -> C:\xxx\Server\CloudService\WebJobs\main_project\bin\Dev\net5.0\main_project.dll
========== Rebuild All: 5 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

But when I want to build Docker image I have a problem:

```
"C:\app\Server\CloudService\WebJobs\main_project\main_project.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\app\Libs\x.BusinessLogic\x.BusinessLogic.csproj" (default target) (4:2) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(819,5): 
  error : The BaseOutputPath/OutputPath property is not set for project 'x.BusinessLogic.csproj'.  
  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Dev'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  
  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
```

Dockerfile `msbuild` command (`CONFIGURATION = Dev`):

```
ARG CONFIGURATION
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
RUN msbuild Server/CloudService/WebJobs/main_project/main_project.csproj /p:Configuration=%CONFIGURATION%
```

Comment: You can use `SetConfiguration` in `ProjectReference`, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019#projectreference), but I don't know whether this achievable from command line